# Exchange 2010 Send connector

Tags: exchange-2010, connector, smtp

How can i specifie that any email from user@abc.com use send connector 1 and any other users use send connector 2?

I'm asking taht because we are going the path of doing online archiving but we have 1 email address that is use to send out emails from our software and it sends more than the limit from our archiving provider.

We have exchange 2010 sp2.

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Exchange 2010 will let you create send connectors for specific destination domains, but not for specific sender addresses.

To solve your archiving limit problem, I suggest you setup an smtp server, e.g. Postfix or EXIM.  Postfix is fairly easy to setup if all you're doing is routing mail to the internet.

If your software is simply sending messages via smtp, just point it at your new server, and you're done.  If it's connecting to Exchange in some other way (e.g. MAPI, EWS, etc.) then you could point all outbound mail from Exchange at the new smtp server, and then configure sender-based routing in postfix/exim.